# Flutter android emulator crashes when trying to open the camera to scan a QR code

Tags: android, flutter

I have an application that is using the camera to read a QR code.
I am using Android Studio.
I have configured the emulator to use the camera of the Mac.
It used to work before and I can't figure out why it doesn't work anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Here are the dependencies of my app:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.0
  receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.5
```

This is the code that tries to open the camera and read the QR code:

```
        void _scanQrCode(BuildContext context) {
                late String url;
                showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return QRCodeScanner(
                    (String qrCodeUrl) {
                        url = qrCodeUrl;
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        playBingo(url);
                    },
                );
            });
        }
```

Here's the log of the error:

```
I/CenterCropStrategy(15154): Preview: 960x1280; Scaled: 1186x1582; Want: 1080x1582
I/CameraPreview(15154): Starting preview
D/CameraInstance(15154): Starting preview
I/AutoFocusManager(15154): Current focus mode 'fixed'; use auto focus? false
E/libEGL  (15154): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
E/mypackage.myapp(15154): [SurfaceTexture-0-15154-0] attachToContext: invalid current EGLDisplay
E/flutter (15154): [ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(182)] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during attachToGLContext (see logcat for details)
E/flutter (15154):  at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(SurfaceTexture.java:295)
E/flutter (15154):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.SurfaceTextureWrapper.attachToGLContext(SurfaceTextureWrapper.java:55)
E/flutter (15154):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (15154):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/flutter (15154):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/flutter (15154):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/flutter (15154):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (15154):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/flutter (15154):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter (15154): 
F/flutter (15154): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1231)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
I/mypackage.myapp(15154): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 83987(5657KB) AllocSpace objects, 24(936KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4472KB/8944KB, paused 47us total 100.465ms
F/crashpad(15427): dlopen: dlopen failed: library "libandroidicu.so" not found: needed by /system/lib/libharfbuzz_ng.so in namespace (default)
F/libc    (15154): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 15154 (mypackage.myapp), pid 15154 (mypackage.myapp)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86_arm:11/RSR1.201013.001/6903271:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2021-10-17 08:57:45+0200
pid: 15154, tid: 15154, name: mypackage.myapp  >>> com.mypackage.myapp <<<
uid: 10155
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1231)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00003b32  ecx 00003b32  edx 00000006
    edi e48b081e  esi ffdd2830
    ebp e9ef6b90  esp ffdd27d8  eip e9ef6b99
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
      #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #02 pc 00076511  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+209) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #03 pc 01375aca  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #04 pc 013ae8fb  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #05 pc 01381c65  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #06 pc 0137434a  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #07 pc 0137414f  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #08 pc 013a6bc3  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #09 pc 013a37e6  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #10 pc 013a6f33  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #11 pc 013a37e6  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #12 pc 013a5c84  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #13 pc 013a37e6  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #14 pc 013a6f33  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #15 pc 013a37e6  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #16 pc 013a6f33  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #17 pc 013a37e6  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #18 pc 013a6f33  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #19 pc 013a37e6  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #20 pc 013a3795  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #21 pc 013a4a79  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #22 pc 01395ca7  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #23 pc 013fc167  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #24 pc 013fcf8d  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #25 pc 013fde5c  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #26 pc 013a8cbd  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #27 pc 013fc7a4  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #28 pc 013fc433  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #29 pc 0140c4e4  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #30 pc 013ac89b  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #31 pc 013afabf  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #32 pc 013af9d0  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #33 pc 013b6d02  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #34 pc 013b6d30  /data/app/~~FljEifuq7NDS0O7fhY6Ofw==/com.mypackage.myapp-CzyBbSiT7dKO4fvfFbhfbQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 5ed38fd537848ce662aaf4326fd6bc527ef1386c)
      #35 pc 00019337  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+39) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
      #36 pc 0001a367  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+1127) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
      #37 pc 00019e96  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+118) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
      #38 pc 0010ef8b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, int)+59) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
      #39 pc 0021be48  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+136) (BuildId: 9a9778e61b43d349325d0bb85244bd9bc95ff387)
      #40 pc 02011c16  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (offset 0x2000000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+230)
      #41 pc 0013b922  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #42 pc 001d0381  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+241) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #43 pc 00386701  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+385) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #44 pc 0037aa3e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1070) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #45 pc 007a11b7  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+967) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #46 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #47 pc 003968f0  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x92b000) (android.os.Looper.loop+156)
      #48 pc 0036fb02  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.16375758241455872412)+370) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #49 pc 00379c1f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+207) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #50 pc 0037b4b5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+2117) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #51 pc 0018e613  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+81395) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #52 pc 00142de2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #53 pc 001a1688  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main)
      #54 pc 0036fa8e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.16375758241455872412)+254) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #55 pc 00379b00  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+176) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #56 pc 0078b325  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1061) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #57 pc 0014220d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #58 pc 0013baf2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #59 pc 001d0392  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #60 pc 00630008  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1464) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #61 pc 005886a0  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+80) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #62 pc 0008a778  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+168) (BuildId: b386118502376442aa402e8d28c29e95a6eb8614)
      #63 pc 0013b922  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #64 pc 001d0381  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+241) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #65 pc 00386701  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+385) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #66 pc 0037aa3e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1070) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #67 pc 007a11b7  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+967) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #68 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #69 pc 0044928e  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x125d000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
      #70 pc 0036fb02  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.16375758241455872412)+370) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #71 pc 00379b00  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+176) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #72 pc 0078b325  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1061) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #73 pc 0014220d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #74 pc 00893656  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2102) (BuildId: 9a9778e61b43d349325d0bb85244bd9bc95ff387)
      #75 pc 0013baf2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #76 pc 001d0392  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #77 pc 0062e653  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, char*)+579) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #78 pc 0062eb25  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+85) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #79 pc 004ce64f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+735) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
      #80 pc 0008f90e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+62) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
      #81 pc 00098c8e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+910) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
      #82 pc 00003804  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1588) (BuildId: c5eedbfb6130af84c3db8e121fb1202e)
      #83 pc 000522e3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+115) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
Lost connection to device.
```